# How were the slow-motion scenes in the movie Cashback made?

Tags: film-techniques, cashback

*Cashback* (2006) has some famous slow-motion scenes in a supermarket, where the camera moves slowly through a frozen moment, but with a single person acting in normal motion.

Does anyone know how these scenes were made?

If CGI was involved, there is obviously no need to explain anything as you can do "anything" with CGI, but my impression is that this was made without any form of CGI.

In particular, there is a moment where the normal character is pulling down the sweater of one of the frozen characters, which really makes you wonder how the shots were made.

Comment: Related if not duplicate - https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/walking-around-someone-who-is-moving-in-slow-motion

Comment: There is a 19 minute (and rather NSFW) "making of" on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XcWwcUo-cA . I've skimmed through it but didn't immediately notice any section explaining this scene. Considering that the movie is actually an expansion of his original short (the short is part of the movie) and was shot on a limited budget, I doubt it involved much CGI. Here is the short film: https://vimeo.com/1924440 .

Comment: To me, nothing suggests anything more complicated than actors holding their breath. They probably didn't even have to remove eye blinks. Only the flying milk container with the droplets is a tiny FX challenge - my guess is a matte on a glass window. -- Then there's a different scene with the protagonist in normal speed filling the shelves on the left and the rest in timelapse, which is most likely a simple split-screen